# Changing main module to a normal function in python

Tags: python, function, module

I am trying to change the main module to a normal function.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     #some code
```

I defined another function called startapp() and then call this function in the main module:

```
def startapp():
   #some code


if __name__ == '__main__':
   startapp()
```

However, my program does not run as desired after I made the changes, so I was wondering if this is the correct way to do it. Anyone knows ?

Comment: Not nearly enough info. What exactly is your code, what should it do, what *does* it do? It could be an simple bug in the code, it could be some namespace magic gone wrong, it could be nearly anything. My educated guess will be that you've done something wrong with `sys.argv`, but that's just a guess.

Comment: do a simple print in the function, and if it prints, you know it's working (up to some point)

Answer (score 0):

What you described is the standard, correct way to do it.

Why you're not getting desired results after the changes indicates that there is some other problem.  We would need more information to help you out.